# Citing in Latex, order by the appearance

Tags: citing

Is there a way to cite the references by the order of their appearance in a document?

Right now, I worked with `\cite{book1}` command, and I wrote all of the references at the end of report using `\bibitem{book1} Author, Year etc.`.

Comment: According to [Wikibooks: Manually managing references](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References), the document author (you) is in charge of sorting the bibliography.

Comment: that is a default behaviour if you use bibtex (or the newer biblatex) but if you hand write the bibliography you need sort the bibitem commands into the right order.